# How to setup SPFolder so title is editable separate from name?

Tags: sharepoint-2007, wss-3.0

I have users that really like Loooooooooooooooooooooooong file paths.

I know the two fields are separate and that SharePoint automatically updates Title when using the edit properties for a folder.  In the past, I've accidentally got SharePoint to have additional metadata on folder, but I've not been able to reproduce this behavior.

How do I make Title editable on a Folder?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 0):

[Lists.UpdateList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.updatelist%28office.12%29.aspx) will allow for you to edit some, not all, metadata for the list itself.